# Convert array to separate values

Tags: php

In my PHP script there is this part `->input(1, 0, 1)->output(0);` and as you can see it needs separate numbers as input. I want to change it in a way so that it gets input from a posted variable `$data = $_POST['data'];`.
However, this is an array and I don't know how to convert it to separate numbers. I tried this already, but that didn't work:

```
$data = $_POST['part1'];

$comma_separated = implode(", ", $data);
$comma_separated = str_replace("'", "", $comma_separated);

try
{
    $objNetwork = Network::loadFromFile('xor.dat');
}
    catch(Exception $e)
{
    print 'Creating a new one...';

    $objNetwork = new Network;

    $objValues = new Values;

    $objValues->train()
              ->input($comma_separated)->output(0);

    $objValues->saveToFile('values_xor.dat');

    unset($objValues);
}
```

I think it's because it's still a string.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php. It lets you call a function, passing array as if each item was a separate parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php. It lets you call a function, passing array as if each item was a separate parameter.

```
// Create an array from your POST variable.
$comma_separated = explode(",", $_POST['val']);

call_user_func_array("function_name", $comma_separated);
// Same as calling function_name($comma_separated[0], $comma_separated[1] ...);
```

In your case, when you've got an array of your values you can do this (Where `$vals` is your array of values):

```
$objValues->train();
call_user_func_array(array($objValues, 'input'), $vals);
$objValues->output(0);
```

Alternatively, you might want to look at re-writing your input function to take a single parameter and have it split them by comma using `explode()`

Comment: Hmm, this might be what I'm looking for, but I don't think it suits the current code, because it's not really a function. This is the complete part: `try
{
  $objNetwork = Network::loadFromFile('xor.dat');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
  print 'Creating a new one...';
 
  $objNetwork = new Network;
 
  $objValues = new Values;
 
  $objValues->train()
            ->input($comma_separated)->output(0);
 
  $objValues->saveToFile('values_xor.dat');
 
  unset($objValues);
}
`

Comment: I also added it to the question.